# My .htaccess code for apache not working right. Redirection is wrong

Tags: .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ ./msadmin/index.php?string=$1 [NC,L]
```

after writeing https://example.com/msadmin/ redirecting to 
https://example.com/msadmin/index.php?string=https://example.com/msadmin

which part is wrong?
I need to go to https://example.com/msadmin/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all of your code with this:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ msadmin/index.php?string=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Make sure to test it in a new browser.